# Querying subclasses through Fuseki

Tags: sparql, ontology, fuseki

I use the following simple SPARQL query to obtain a list of classes of an ontology and their subclasses through Fuseki:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?object
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object }
```

This way, I can see the complete `URI` of all the classes. Now, I would like to query the subclasses of a specific class, say `abc`

I look at the output of the query and I see the URI of the class in focus `abc` is this:

```
http://blahblahblah/file.owl#abc
```

So, I pose the following SPARQL query to get its subclasses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf http://blahblahblah/file.owl#abc }
```

But the output is empty. I also trying enclosing the URL within single quote and double quotes, to no avail.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf 'http://blahblahblah/file.owl#abc' }

SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf "http://blahblahblah/file.owl#abc" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [syntax for IRIs in SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#QSynIRI) encloses IRIs in angle brackets (`<` and `>`).  Your query should be written as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf <http://blahblahblah/file.owl#abc> }
```